# Size of java.awt.Color object

Tags: java, jquery, sockets, lag, object-serialization

I have a program in which I am using an ObjectStream over sockets. Code for the class Im sending looks like the following.

```
class Snake{
Point[] p = new Point[50];
Direction move;
public int length;
int score;
String player;
Color snakecolor;
boolean gameover;
//Other Functions go here//    
}
```

This Class is sent repeatedly over the socket. However its showing a bit of lag. Would it make that much of a difference if instead of sending the Color object I send an RGB code(integer values)? How could I possibly make my program lag free?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/52682/833336 in order to determinate the size of a Color object against the integer values and make your own conclusions,  at first I don't think it can be the cause of the lag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.awt.Color), the following fields of `Color` are serialized:

```
int value
float[] frgbvalue
float[] fvalue
float falpha
ColorSpace cs
```

`ColorSpace` [has the following serialized fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/serialized-form.html#java.awt.color.ColorSpace):

```
int type
int numComponents
```

`frgbValue` and `fvalue` contain 3 elements, so the total size is 40 bytes. Just sending RGB would be 12 bytes. I don't think that's gonna solve your lag.